# Screen sensitivity across Android devices

Tags: android, touch, touchscreen

I have encountered a really weird scenario during my tests and maybe you can light me.

**Scenario:**
The application consists in a Surfaceview in which I handle the touch event. I have a image on the screen and the user put's his finger on it and then takes it back. Just like a short button pressing.

**What goes wrong:**

**Samsung Galaxy S** with SuperAmoled screen - the touch events fired are: Down and then Up. just like it is normally

**Nexus One, Desire** - the touch events fired are: Down, Move, Move, Up The move gesture is small like +- 1 px but there is. Now imagine the fact that I have code that is fired in Move event.

So testing on my Galaxy S everything works wonderful, testing on Nexus it fails as it doesn't react as supposed to.

**My Questions:**

- is there any way to prevent this ?
- is this because of screen type and sensitivity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean flag to prevent code to run in Move Event by setting flag to true in down event and then call the methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to device display sensitivity. I met this breaking behaviour on samsung galaxy 10 and 10+. When the finger was just not moving the display was capturing those micro-movements and sending me moves, breaking usual tap logic.

Solved this my implementing a threshold in points (20pts in my case, movement distance pixels*density away from the DOWN location) to totally filter out those micro-movements.

The threshold would be checked for the first Move event only. So until the threshold is outpassed all movements are ignored, but if the Move is finally depassing the threshold all further movements are accepted until the next finger down event.